# scikit learn cross validation classification_report

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to have metrics per class label and an aggregate confusion matrix from a cross validation in scikit learn.

I wrote a method that performs a cross-validation for scikit learn that sums the confusion matrices and also stores all the predicted labels. Then, it calls scikit learn methods to print out the metrics.

The code below should run with any recent scikit learn installation, you can test it out with any dataset.

Is below the correct way to gather an aggregate `cm` and a `classification_report` when doing StratifiedKFold cross validation?

```
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.cross_validation import StratifiedKFold
import numpy as np

def customCrossValidation(self, X, y, classifier, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0):
    ''' Perform a cross validation and print out the metrics '''
    skf = StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=n_folds, shuffle=shuffle, random_state=random_state)
    cm = None
    y_predicted_overall = None
    y_test_overall = None
    for train_index, test_index in skf:
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
        classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
        # collect the y_predicted per fold
        if y_predicted_overall is None:
            y_predicted_overall = y_predicted
            y_test_overall = y_test
        else: 
            y_predicted_overall = np.concatenate([y_predicted_overall, y_predicted])
            y_test_overall = np.concatenate([y_test_overall, y_test])
        cv_cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predicted)
        # sum the cv per fold
        if cm is None:
            cm = cv_cm
        else:
            cm += cv_cm
    print (metrics.classification_report(y_test_overall, y_predicted_overall, digits=3))
    print (cm)
```

Comment: can you add some data and sample output? when i ran with random data the numbers added up for me

Comment: I re-checked with some make_classification datasets, you are correct, the values make sense. I rephrased the question, as I did not find such a method above online, it might help others.